# Building a linker

Tags: compiler-construction, linker

There is a lot of information out there about designing and implementing a compiler, but i can't find anything about linkers.

I'm very interested in these subjects but I can't find any information about linkers. 
Does anyone know a tutorial, book, etc. about linker design and implementation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The classic book on linkers: [Linkers and Loaders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960). A draft of it is available [online](http://web.archive.org/web/20181126073435/https://www.iecc.com/linker/).

Ian Lance Taylor recently implemented a new ELF linker ([gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29)). He wrote a series of [blog posts](http://www.airs.com/blog/index.php?s=linker) explaining a lot of details. Start [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38).